# Regular Expression for two or more dots should be separated as dot space

Tags: java, regex

I have inputs like this.

```
And I walked 0.69 miles. I had a burger..I took tea...I had a coffee
```

And my goal is to convert two or more dots to a single dot and then a space so that input become correct according to grammar proper ending. Target output is:

```
And I walked 0.68 miles. I had a burger. I took tea. I had a coffee
```

I have made a regular expression for this is as:

```
[\\.\\.]+
```

I checked it on [Regex Tester](http://www.regextester.com/) it will not work as I wished. As it will also included `0.69` and ending of this line `.`  too which I don't want. If anybody can help me in this I will be thankful to you.

Comment: @CraigR8806 And location is wrong. That's what I wanted to highlight.

Comment: I see, you need to move your + like so: `\\.\\.+`.  Your version will only match even number of periods: .. .... ......

Comment: @CraigR8806 No, the \\. are in a match from group [], (the double \\ is for java escape and regex escape), so he is matching . or . 1+ times

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\.{2,}", ". ");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EgOjrM/1)

`\\.{2,}` matches 2 or more consecutive dots and `". "` replaced them by a dot and space.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this :

```
String str = "And I walked 0.69 miles. I had a burger..I took tea...I had a coffee";
String result = str.replaceAll("\\.{2,}", ". ");
```

**Output**

```
And I walked 0.68 miles. I had a burger. I took tea. I had a coffee
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should work

```
[\.]+[\.]+
```

This will match 2 or more continuous periods. You can then replace each match with a period and space

Answer (score 1):

You need to pull the first \. out to match that, then 1+ \. so like

```
\.\.+ or Java string escaped \\.\\.+
```

[\.\.] Will match \ or . or \ or . witch is a redundant check on a single character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.replaceAll()` to accomplish this:

```
myString.replaceAll("\\.[\\.]+", ". ");
```

Your `regex` is slightly wrong also it should be `\.[\.]+`. In `Java` you will have to escape the `\` so it will be `\\.[\\.]+`...

Comment: Replace it with ". " not with " .", the space comes after the dot

Comment: I think for two or more it should be '(\\.\\.+)'